# What comprises of a 'sensible' coordinate transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I am doing the course on general relativity at my university and have been struggling with covariant and contravariant vectors. I understand that components of contravariant vectors transform in a way that is 'opposite' to how the basis vectors transform. This makes some geometric sense as well. But my question is when we talk about coordinate transformations, which ones are we talking about specifically? I have seen references to rotations about an axis as examples. But surely these aren't all of them. There must also be transformations that are not useful. Can someone please elaborate with examples?

Comment: The set of all coordinate transformations considered in general relativity is the diffeomorphism group $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ of the space manifold $M$, which consists of every differentiable map $f : M \to M$ that has a differentiable inverse.

Comment: All smooth (differentiable) transformations that you can imagine.